Bokeh interactive plot: Option to select/deselect all legends?
is there a way to add checkbox to select/deselect all legends in a Bokeh interactive plot?

Bokeh v3.6.0, Python 3.12.6

Example code below:
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, GOOG, IBM, MSFT

p = figure(width=800, height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to mute the corresponding lines'

for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8,
           muted_color=color, muted_alpha=0.2, legend_label=name)

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="mute"

show(p)

Imagine I had to deal w/ large num of legends to interact with. It would be nice to have a checkbox to deselect all legends, and only turn ON the ones I need to compare data.
